# How to transfer large amounts of data via bluetooth on iOS

Tags: ios, bluetooth

If [you have to use bluetooth LE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18214023/how-to-use-bluetooth-classic-instead-of-le?noredirect=1#comment26697927_18214023). How do you transfer large amounts of data OR data at a faster rate, via bluetooth on iOS?

Answer (score 0):

You try not to. You can't go faster. To transfer lots of data you send lots of small packets.

Basically, don't use BTLE.

Comment: I get it. My question is what is the alternative to BTLE but still using bluetooth

Comment: Just normal, non-low-energy Bluetooth. What devices are you transferring between?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my first post got additional answers and I just need the ExternalAccessory Framework