# How to connect iOS with BLE and previous versions of Bluetooth

Tags: ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

we are about to start developing an app for iOS that reads data sent via Bluetooth from a device. Which framework should we use if the Bluetooth device that sends the data is not BLE 4.0? In addition to this, if it is possible to develop to app by using a different framework, will the same app also be able to connect to BLE 4.0?
Any pointer is highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance for any pointer.

Answer (score 1):

The framework you are looking for is the `ExternalAccessory.framework` (although there are limitations). You can use it and the `Corebluetooth.framework` inside the same app, but they will not be related on which devices they can connect to. `Corebluetooth` is Bluetooth low energy only.  Check this answer and the related links for more information on using the `ExternalAccessory.framework` :

[How to use bluetooth classic instead of le](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18214023/how-to-use-bluetooth-classic-instead-of-le/18214742#18214742)