# Bluetooth vs Bluetooth low energy on iOS

Tags: ios, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

I'm trying to get the name (only the name) of all bluetooth devices near me (classic bluetooth and BLE). to be more specific i need to know when the user is near his car kit device bluetooth.

I tried using CoreBluetoothFramework but it can only create connection with BLE devices.

I'm not sure that all the car kits uses "Apple's MFi license" so i'm not sure i can use External Accessory.

Answer (score 0):

Use IOBluetooth for Bluetooth classic. See for example IOBluetoothDevice and IOBluetoothDeviceInquiry classes. If you want to see any device you need to use both IOBluetooth and Core Bluetooth. The MFi is needed for developing new profiles under Bluetooth classic, you shouldn't need it for an application that just detects devices.

For iOS you can try the ExternalAccessories framework for Bluetooth classic (IOBluetooth is not supported). See this question for relevant details: [How to use bluetooth classic instead of le](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18214023/how-to-use-bluetooth-classic-instead-of-le)

Comment: This framework is from 2010 - are you sure its ok to use it?

Comment: IOBlueTooth is only for mac OS :(

Comment: IOBluetooth should be as good as Bluetooth classic ;) I wasn't thinking so much about the iOS restrictions; the answer is updated.

Answer (score -2):

```
1. Bluetooth Classic and Bluetooth Low Energy both different.
2. BT classic is old version of BT(BT 2.0).
3. BLE 4.0 and later version control by core bluetooth library.
4. Cant communicate with BT classic via core bluetooth library.
5. Latest version of BLE 5.
6. BLE 5 available only on iPhone 8, 8+ and X(10).
7. Cant find/show BLE in iOS bluetooth settings.
6. Only BT classic find/show in iOS bluetooth settings.
```

Comment: If this is an answer then please add some explanation too