# Can you access a bluetooth device via the ExternalAccessory framework after pairing with CoreBluetooth?

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, external-accessory, mfi

I have a Bluetooth device enrolled in the MFi program. I am able to pair the device via Bluetooth in the iPhone settings, and then use **Apple's EADemo** example code to access the device via the `ExternalAccessory` framework.

However, I'm wondering if it's possible to first **silently** pair in the background via `CoreBluetooth`, and then use the `ExternalAcessory` framework to communicate with the device?

I've run some experiements and after pairing with `CoreBluetooth`, the `ExternalAcessory` framework shows no connected devices. This might be as CoreBluetooth opperates over Bluetooth Low Energy, and `ExternalAccessory` perhaps opperates over Bluetooth Classic.

Despite of this, it would be a much better user experience to pair the device from within an app, rather than needing to leave the app to access the settings. If anyone has been in this situation, or has any ideas, please feel free to share any suggestions.

Comment: As you say, Core Bluetooth is only for BLE.  MFi is for legacy Bluetooth.  The two don't interoperate

Comment: @larromba - did you get any work around ? i am also stuck at the same point .. Please respond

Comment: @MridulGupta I havn't found an answer, but connecting via `CoreBluetooth` won't mean your device shows in the `ExternalAcessory` framework. I suspect you could theoretically connect using `CoreBluetooth`, and trigger the device to try connecting via Bluetooth Regular so it appears in the `ExternalAcessory` framework, however if it hasn't paired for the first time, you still need to pair it manually via the iOS Bluetooth settings. To do anything with the `ExternalAccessory` framework, your hardware must be enrolled in the MFi program. Hope that helps

Comment: @larromba Thanks for replying, i got the answer for it , i will respond in answer section.

Comment: @larromba Did you find anything? Or is this silent pairing just not possible, even if the peripheral is MFi approved?

Comment: @Ixx This was a long time ago, but I remember not finding a solution to the question posted above, because it seemed both frameworks use different bluetooth technologies, as Paulw11 confirmed above

Answer (score 0):

No need to rely on the `CoreBluetooth` framework if you are working with `ExternalAcessory` 
`double delayInSeconds = 2;
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        [[EAAccessoryManager sharedAccessoryManager] showBluetoothAccessoryPickerWithNameFilter:nil completion:nil];
    });`

Put this code on a click of a button or wherever you want, this code will popup a window which will show the list of available MFI program devices, you need to select the device and it will get connected.

After successful connection , you will get a notification `EAAccessoryDidConnectNotification`, you need to listen this and you can get the connect accessory using 
`- (void)_accessoryDidConnect:(NSNotification *)notification {
EAAccessory *connectedAccessory = [[notification userInfo] objectForKey:EAAccessoryKey];
}`

@larromba- i hope you were looking for this.

Comment: Thanks for posting this. This is useful code, but I meant about using `CoreBluetooth` to connect silently in the background (without needing a picker). It would be great if you could connect to an external accessory without needing user interaction. I'll update my answer to be more specific.