# Is it possible to connect bluetooth classic (Bluetooth 2 ) with iPhone?

Tags: ios, bluetooth

I'm developing a bluetooth app.My bluetooth device is 2.0

Is it possible to connect bluetooth 2.0 device with my iPhone 6?

My device don't see bluetooth classic. Any advice or sample code please?

Comment: I'm sure you need external framework.refer this https://stackoverflow.com/a/18214742/2218874

Comment: If your device is MFi certified then you can use the external accessory framework.  If not then you cannot do anything with it from an app.

Comment: For non-MFi, this is possible if you are targeting only jail-broken devices. I'm using [BTStack](https://github.com/bluekitchen/btstack) to connect my BT device w/ my jail-broken iphones. You can download binary via Cydia.

Comment: my MacBook see 2.0 device but iPhone don't :/