# Xamarin and Bluetooth Classic

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, bluetooth, ios-bluetooth

I'm looking for guidance on where to start developing a solution for working with a Bluetooth classic device within a Xamarin project.

I'm struggling to filter out all the LE recommendations when searching.

Does anyone have a start point, ideally beginning with iOS where I can implement a full bluetooth solution?

I have a device where I have a low level serial API so I need to manage connecting, opening a socket and communicating on the byte level through a socket using the classic bluetooth stack.

Comment: You may be interested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/18214742/2708650

Comment: `ExternalAccessory.framework` should be the framework you are looking for.